# Select box with json content

Tags: jquery, json, select

I'm building some Html from a JSON file.

The problem is that I need to fill a select box with content from the json file. I tried several solutions from the forum but can't get it to work. I think it has something to do with appending the stuff because I also have different html being build.

What I have is this:

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data){ 
........ etc
quickCartHtml += '<form id="variants" action=""><select id="options" name="option">';


var options = '';

  $.each(product.variants, function (index, variant) {

  options += '<option value="' + variant.id + '" />' + variant.title + '</option>';

  });  

$('#options').append(options);

quickCartHtml += '</select></form>';
```

When I use console.log everything seems to work. Therefore I think I'm doing something wrong with appending to quickCartHtml.

Anyone a suggestion?

Comment: nowhere in your code are you actually using `data`, which is where I presume your "json file" exists.

Comment: I assume your quickCartHtml is rendered BEFORE you are trying to append to the #options element?

Comment: Currently you are not "appending [your options] to quickCartHtml"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer to my question so I'm posting this to help somebody else:

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data){ 
........ etc


options = '';

  $.each(product.variants, function (index, variant) {

  options += '<option value="' + variant.id + '">' + variant.title + '</option>';

  });  

 quickCartHtml += '<form id="variants" action=""><select id="options" name="option">'+options+'</select>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#options').html(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the `<select>` has not been built yet when you call the append so you need to keep adding to the variable and then append the whole thing:

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data) {........etc
    quickCartHtml += '<form id="variants" action=""><select id="options" name="option">';


    // unnecessary
    // var options = '';

    $.each(product.variants, function (index, variant) {

        quickCartHtml += '<option value="' + variant.id + '" />' + variant.title + '</option>';

    });

    // $('#options').append(options);

    quickCartHtml += '</select></form>';

    // now append quickCarthtml to a div or something
    $('div').append(quickCartHtml);
```

Answer (score 0):

you must append quickCartHtml to something before you can select #options which could be done like so:

> $('#target').append(quickCartHtml);

And also you must append your generated options to #options like so:

> $options = $('#options');
>
> $.each(product.variants, function (index, variant) {
>
> ```
> $options.append($('<option>', {value: variant.id, html: variant.title}));
> ```
>
> }